# Randomly assign instance variables?

Tags: ruby, initialization, instance-variables

I'm not sure if this can be done, but I figure I'd ask.

I currently have this:

```
class Color

attr_accessor :is_blue, :is_green, :is_brown, :is_yellow, :is_orange

def initialize
  @is_blue = false
  @is_green = false
  @is_brown = false
  @is_yellow = false
  @is_orange = false
end

def random_starting_color
  starting_color = [is_blue, is_green, is_brown, is_yellow, :is_orange].sample
  starting_color = true
end
end
```

As you would have guess, `random_starting_color` doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can go about re-assigning a new color when I create a new Color object?

Comment: Looks like you could use some kind of an enum here instead.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you mean to do is something like this:

```
ivars = [:@is_blue, :@is_green, :@is_brown, :@is_yellow, :@is_orange]
instance_variable_set(ivars.sample, true)
```

Comment: Awesome, works perfect! I didn't know a instance_variable_set existed so thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You should not store the color in different variables, but just in one. Otherwise you need to handle what should happen if red, brown and blue is true. That only works well went you have a real RGB model, but that you would need countable values instead of booleans.

```
class Color
  COLORS = [:blue, :green, :brown, :yellow, :orange]

  attr_reader :color

  def initialize(color = :random)
    @color = color
  end

  def color=(color)
    if color == :random
      @color = COLORS.sample
    else
      @color = color if COLORS.include?(color)
    end
  end

  COLORS.each do |color|
    def #{color}?
      @color == :#{color}
    end
  end
end

c = Color.new     
c.color           # => a random color out all possible COLORS
c.color = :blue
c.color           # => :blue
c.blue?           # => true
c.yellow?         # => false

c.color = :random
c.color           # => a random color out all possible COLORS
```